# Scale image according to screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two images that are designed for a 1024 x 768 resolution which I want to use in a higher resolution. The two images need to line up so the circle from the first image is inbetween the second image.

I got it working with my desired resolution but the problem is that for higher resolution the image is not big enough. I thought about setting the width on the images using the formula `((100 - ($(window).width() - 1024) / 1024 * 100) + 100)`. The problem though is that this doesn't line the images up correctly.

This is the code i'm currently using:

```
<div id="helperLines" class="lines">
    <img src="HelperLines.png" alt="HelperLines" />
</div>

<div id="startingLine" class="lines">
    <img src="StartingLine.png" alt="StartingLine" />
</div>

.lines
{
    position: absolute;
}

#helperLines
{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#startingLine
{
    left: 97px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4SLnS/2/)

Here is a image of my desired effect:
[image: 1024x768 resolution]

And here is the image in 1920x1080:
[image: 1920x1080 resolution]

Comment: Why did you not just use 1 image instead of 2 if you want them always to line up?

Comment: Because I need to fade the first image in (Using jQuery) then fade the second image in afterwards.

Comment: You could make two images out of it with both the same size and give them both `top: 0; left: 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the images as background and use `background-size:contain`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SLnS/4/)

In this case the line in the bottom image should be shifted to the right a bit, so it scales evenly.

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the postioning of the second image to be form the top as well.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4SLnS/3/)

```
#startingLine
{
    top:265px; /* approx */
    left:95px; /* approx */
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say the bottom image needs to always be at the bottom.